# What's the difference between stackoverflow.com and superuser.com?

Tags: help

Can you explain the main difference between Stack Overflow and Super User, especially regarding the types of questions appropriate for each? What are the pros and cons of each in general use case? I'm looking to understand where to post my questions correctly.

Comment: Superuser = computer software or computer hardware. StackOverflow = specific coding, algorithm, or language problems. There is some overlap, but if you're not working with code, then stick to superuser.

Comment: Thank you, @Cpt.Whale

Comment: @Eugene may I point you towards the Help sections clearly indicated in the upper navigation for both these sites? There you will find details regarding what is on and off topic. Also, there are Meta sub-sites for each of these where you can and should ask questions like this. Do not ask questions ABOUT these sites ON these sites.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will bear it in mind